# Efficient way to reuse buffer

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management

I have a piece of code that is reading into a buffer of constant size, which can be simplified to basically

```
{
    constexpr std::size_t buffer_size = 262144u;
    std::vector<char> buffer(buffer_size);          // vector is reallocated every time
    read(buffer.data(), buffer.size());             // write into the buffer
    ...
}
```

For performance I was considering making the vector `static` to reduce re-allocating every time this function is called, something like this

```
{
    constexpr std::size_t buffer_size = 262144u;
    static std::vector<char> buffer(buffer_size);   // vector is allocated only once
    buffer.assign(buffer.size(), '\0');             // "reset" the vector contents
    read(buffer.data(), buffer.size());             // write into the buffer
    ...
}
```

I tried [benchmarking these two methods](https://quick-bench.com/q/yWeODG29nWGUvMklQDTo0wJMauQ) and they appear to be nearly identical (for Clang with `-O3`) in terms of performance.

Is this linked benchmark a good test for the behavior I described?
Are one of these two methods "obviously" preferred over the other, from a performance perspective?

Comment: `preferred over the other, from a performance perspective?` from performance (and memory) perspective, i've seen projects using _only_ global variables. But [there are problems with global variables](https://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad) and don't forget [rules of optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimizationClub). It's funny how, in your benchmark, doing the `memset(buffer, '\0'` part takes way longer time then calling `malloc`. If you lower the buffer size in your benchmark, you'll see the difference. Still, in your benchmark, static vector is faster.

Comment: Do you need to clear the vector, if you are immediately going to read data into it?

Comment: The function that will write to the buffer (`read` in my example) is a black-box 3rd party code, so I'm not sure what the exact requirements are. E.g. can it be full of arbitrary data, should it be "zeroed out", etc. I think that's a great point though, if I can skip writing to the whole buffer that should be a clear winner.

Comment: You are measuring both allocating elements and initializing them. If you want to compare just the time to allocate the memory, it might be better to skip the `buffer.assign()` line, use the default constructor for `vector`, and `reserve` the space. Of course, don't call `read` either since the memory is allocated but not initialized, but your benchmark already doesn't involve `read`. This might tell you that the time to initialize the data dwarfs the time to allocate it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're not really "reusing" your vector since you're zeroing out the whole thing.  If you're going to write into the buffer anyways, then you don't have to zero it out.

This could potentially be an issue if you're writing the entire vector out somewhere that a user could see it since you would potentially leak part of whatever was in the array before, but it's somewhat rare that that's an issue.

Here's your benchmark without the clear and instead just writing in 1024 bytes to simulate file reading.  https://quick-bench.com/q/Qkb0NTMAQ0kaydKbdpOPhQGgR6U

Comment: The purpose of reusing the buffer is to avoid memory allocation. This is much more expensive than zeroing it.